# How to set audio position in Sdl_mixer

Tags: android, audio, sdl, sdl-mixer

I am using SDL_mixer library to play multiple audio together.

I am able to play music together and it working fine, but i want to add a delay in playing audio.For example play first audio from 3 to 10 seconds and second audio from 5 to 14 seconds and third audio should play from 0 to 14.

How can i do this with sdl_audiomixer library?